# Imagen desenfocada después de Hover

Tags: html, css, css3

quizás me puedan ayudar a resolver algo referente a un hover sobre una imagen.

Estoy aplicando un `transition` a una imagen y en el evento hover aplico un `transform`lo que sucede es que mis imágenes se desenfocan al poner el cursor encima, como si hiciera un `Scale` pero no le estoy indicando que lo aplique

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.moveCard {
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.moveCard:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -10px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
  <div class="list-card bg-white h-100 rounded overflow-hidden position-relative shadow-sm">
    <div class="list-card-image">
      <a href="product_details.php?valueId=<?php echo $prodId ?>&idCate=1" class="text-dark">
        <div class="p-3">

          <img src="https://cdn.forzaitalianfootball.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/online_gambling_online_growth-800x504.jpg" class="img-fluid item-img w-100 mb-3 moveCard" style="width:234px;height:147px">
          <h6 class="textHTitles">Nombre Card</h6>
          <h7 class="textHTitles">Descripcion Card</h7>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="container" style="text-align:center">
              <h6><a class="btn btn-link" href="product_details.php?valueId=<?php echo $prodId ?>&idCate=1">Ver info</a></h6>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

La imagen se mira bien pero después de aplicar la transición desenfoca la imagen y al quitar el mouse la imagen queda desenfocada también.

Agradecería cualquier comentario.

Comment: en el código que pusiste no se ve el error

Comment: Gracias por responder y si se nota lo que menciono, he actualizado la imagen con unas letras para que veas lo que sucede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser que, porque estás moviendo solo el contenedor, y no la imagen. Prueba ambos al mismo tiempo: `.moveCard, .moveCard img { ...}`, o solamente la imagen.

Prueba con este estilo:

```
.moveCard {
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
outline: 0;
}

.moveCard:hover {
 transform: translate(0, -10px);
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, -10px);
}
```